# Dynamically generate buttons C# and ASP.NET and save in database when clicking

Tags: c#, asp.net

Friends, I have a question, I have a button to generate buttons, which generates 5 buttons dynamically and they have a click event that saves a page in my database, but when I click the generated buttons, it reloads the page and does nothing, can you help me please, I already looked in the forum and the answer is not in other similar questions, as long as I hit the generated button, the page reloads, these are deleted and nothing is saved in the database.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace pruebastack
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\camic\\Documents\\prueba.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        protected void btngenerar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for(int i=1; i<=5; i++)
            {
                System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button Button1 = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button();
                Button1.Text = "boton" + i;

                Button1.Click += delegate
                {
                    String insertar = "INSERT INTO pruba values (@nombre)";
                    cn.Open();
                    SqlCommand comandoIn = new SqlCommand(insertar, cn);
                    comandoIn.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre", "https://www.udemy.com/courses/search/?p=" + i + "&q=java");
                    comandoIn.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    cn.Close();
                };

                this.Panel1.Controls.Add(Button1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```